# Webkit vertical tears

Tags: html, css, webkit

[image: Vertical screen tears in content divs]

Hi guys, I am wondering has anyone else ever came up against this problem in webkit, we first noticed it in mac retina laptop, then we seen it was actually happening in chrome on PC as well - so i am guessing it is a webkit rendering problem.

I have been searching a bit, in fact i don't really know what terms to use in search as i have no explanation for it.

I have noticed that when i remove position relative the tears seems to go, also in other computers i can only replicate the problem when i zoom in (ctrl+), removing the relative position does work but it then breaks the absolute positioned slider controls

Site can be found here: http://www.linwoodshealthfoods.com

Any one experienced this before or have a clue what is doing it?

Thanks in advance.
J

Comment: have you tried actually changing your resolution rather than using ctrl+? Had a similar issue, only happened when using ctrl+ zooming

Comment: See no tears in Firefox, Safari. Ctrl+- used.
Are you trying to advertize your site ??? :)

Comment: I see a tearing only when i zoom in to %400, and only on the images below the product sections, not where you describe..

Comment: No no, not advertising my site lol - On my own pc i can only replicate @140% zoom - on the client's laptop it is there at 100% zoom so it is a problem, it is insanely bad on a mac retina as well i guess due to the increased ratio.